# input file capture create a temporary image on IPhone Safari?

Tags: capture, temporary-files

on mobile, it fires mobile camera then take a picture.

then input=file has a the result of the file !

we can access like "input.files[0]"

so that file is 1) on memory ? or 2) temporary file in browser app ?

anyways, 1), or 2) is there a way to clean the memory or delete the temporary image file ?

I tried to set null values the FileReader or
Form reset which is input contains

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) To help you, we need some more details. What programming language are you using? What framework are you using? What are you trying to accomplish? Also take a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)